# SSAS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, openquery

We have a large number of stored procedures where data is pulled from an SSAS cube on the same server as SQL Server, and combined with data from the SQL Server tables.

We currently use a linked server, `openquery` and MDX to pull the data from SSAS. This creates some issues with execution plans since it can't estimate the number of rows that will be returned from SSAS. Is this really the only way to connect SSAS and SQL Server?

Comment: After pulled the data from SSAS cube run the update stat and rebuiding the indexes which might help. Are you haveing problem with pulling the data?

Comment: I find `OPENQUERY` quite an efficient approach. The first query that uses that structure each day is slow but then other stored procs run quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink your architecture - try to include whatever data you are currently pulling from SQL Server tables into the SSAS cube. Then your queries become straight MDX and should be very quick (may need Aggregations).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of data from SQL Server tables and the purpose behind pulling it, there are two approaches that I would suggest:

- If the data from SQL Server tables is used for summarizing and does not change very frequently then you may as well push it into the cube as MOLAP dimensional data. Using this approach, you get the best query performance.
- On the other hand, if it is transactional data and is frequently updated, you can still push it into the cube using [ROLAP storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174915.aspx) and/or [Proactive Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174769.aspx). Using this approach, you can incorporate the latest data into the cube (with minimal latency) but this has some impact on the query performance.

Although, in either case, I agree there would be a considerable amount of rework translating from the stored procedures.